# how to create a AWS EKS cluster with 2 master nodes using Terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

**Hey so I was able to create a EKS cluster with 1 master and 2 nodes using a tutorial I found on net but I need to have 2 masters and I am relatively new to Terraform any help is appreiciated **

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are referring to when you say "master nodes" but that part of the EKS service is opinionated and not adjustable. As part of the cluster control plane we run at least 3 nodes for etcd and additional nodes for the API server. You don't get to decide that topology.